# Change filename of js for eg show.js to show2.js in respond_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have one js file `show.js` that is renderd for the action `def show`:

```
def show
....
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js 
    end
  end
```

My question is how can I change the `respond_to` block, so that it does not respond with `show.js` but for example with `newshow.js`? I ask because I would like to render different `js` dependent on the params! Thanks! I use Rails 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this one would work:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { render :newshow }
end
```